# Trying to add some code to only Archive pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a text widget for only the Archive pages. The first block of code below is what is default for the theme.

```
if (Bunyad::posts()->meta('featured_slider') == 'rev-slider' && function_exists('putRevSlider')) {

    echo '<div class="main-featured"><div class="wrap cf">'
        . do_shortcode('[rev_slider ' . esc_attr(Bunyad::posts()->meta('slider_rev')) .']')
        . '</div></div>';

    return;
}
```

In addition to the code above, I added this second block directly underneath it. The only difference is that I added `&& is_archive()` on the first line to target all Archive pages and also the three lines of code starting at line 5.

```
if (Bunyad::posts()->meta('featured_slider') == 'rev-slider' && function_exists('putRevSlider') && is_archive() {

    echo '<div class="main-featured"><div class="wrap cf">'

        if (!dynamic_sidebar('categories')) :
            _e('', 'bunyad');
        endif;

        . do_shortcode('[rev_slider ' . esc_attr(Bunyad::posts()->meta('slider_rev')) .']')
        . '</div></div>';

    return;
}
```

The result is a blank page so obviously something is wrong here. Is there some kind of way to condense both of these blocks into something more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably giving a white page due to a syntax error. The if block is in the middle of an echo. Try something like:

```
if (Bunyad::posts()->meta('featured_slider') == 'rev-slider' && function_exists('putRevSlider') && is_archive()) {

    echo '<div class="main-featured"><div class="wrap cf">';

    if (!dynamic_sidebar('categories')) :
        _e('', 'bunyad');
    endif;

    echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider ' . esc_attr(Bunyad::posts()->meta('slider_rev')) .']') . '</div></div>';

    return;
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing your code with my second block and I'm still getting a white page.

Comment: The if was missing a closing ) I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the page is showing now, but the three lines of code for the archive pages aren't showing up in the DOM. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding some text in the _e() right now it is empty so it is probably outputting nothing.

Comment: I inputted 'test' within the quotes and it's not showing up.

Comment: Yes, I just double-checked. It's 'categories'.